# Meaning of -if in Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, kotlinx.serialization

For the following Proguard rule(take [Kotlin Serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#android))

```
-if @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable class **
-keepclassmembers class <1> {
    static <1>$Companion Companion;
}
```

Here what is the meaning of `-if` in context with the above rule? I tried looking into official proguard documentation but couldn't find any info around that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote those ProGuard rules. :) The [pull request discussion about these changes may provide relevant background](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/pull/1721).

I understand your confusion, the [ProGuard rules documentation is quite sparse](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage).

> `-if` class_specification
>
> Specifies classes and class members that must be `present` to activate the subsequent keep option (`-keep`,
> `-keepclassmembers`,...). The condition and the subsequent keep option can share wildcards and references to wildcards. For example, you can
> keep classes on the condition that classes with related names exist in
> your project, with frameworks like Dagger and Butterknife.

As written in the comments of the rules you copied this from:

```
# Keep `Companion` object fields of serializable classes.
# This avoids serializer lookup through `getDeclaredClasses` as done for named companion objects.
-if @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable class **
...
```

So, `-if @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable class **` should be read as: for all classes which have the `@Serializable` annotation applied (i.e., "serializable classes"). The `<1>` in `-keepmembers` subsequently refers to the `**` wildcard, i.e., the fully-qualified class name.